# Angle between principal directions of two curvature operators on isometric surfaces.

Tags: differential-geometry, surfaces, curvature

In the [linked paper](https://arxiv.org/pdf/2204.07342.pdf), I am unable to understand how the expression (4) is arrived at??

To elaborate, the authors take the curvature operators of two isometric surfaces $M$ and $\overline{M}$ as $\boldsymbol{\kappa}$ and $\boldsymbol{\overline\kappa}$, and try to simplify an expression of the form

$$ E = \dfrac{\lambda}{1+v^2}\big[(1-v)Tr(\boldsymbol{\kappa}-\boldsymbol{\overline\kappa})^2 - v. Tr^2(\boldsymbol{\kappa}-\boldsymbol{\overline\kappa})\big]$$

where $Tr$ is the trace of the operator and $\lambda, v $ are constants.

Essentially the surface $M$ has been bent isometrically into $\overline{M}$ and the corresponding points on the surfaces are identified via the isometry. They say if $H = \frac{1}{2}(\kappa_1 + \kappa_2)$ is the mean curvature of M and similarly $\overline{H}$ of $\overline{M}$, then writing $D = \frac{1}{2}(\kappa_1 - \kappa_2)$ and respectively $\overline{D}$ for $\overline{M}$, we obtain

$$E = (H-\overline{H})^2 + \gamma(D - \overline{D})^2 +4D\overline{D}\sin^2{\theta},$$

where $\theta$ is the angle between the principal directions of $\boldsymbol{\kappa}$ and $\boldsymbol{\overline{\kappa}}$ and $\gamma = \dfrac{(1+v)}{(1-v)}$. What does this mean precisely??I am unable to figure out the exact definition of $\theta$ in terms of $\boldsymbol{\kappa}$ and $\boldsymbol{\overline{\kappa}}$. That would also help in understanding the derivation.

Comment: They are using the given isometry (and its derivative) to canonically identify corresponding points and tangent spaces at the respective points? It would help to make the question more self-contained.

Comment: @TedShifrin Thank you for your response. Yes the isometry is used to identify corresponding points and the tangent spaces. I have slightly edited the question. I am just unabke to understand how the angle $\theta$ arises or is defined.

Comment: The principal vectors for each surface form an orthogonal set. One set is turned an angle $0\le\theta<\pi/2$ from the other. (Note the possible sign is irrelevant because $\sin^2\theta$ appears.

Comment: @TedShifrin Thank you. So essentially the principal curvature of the deformed surface is $\overline\kappa_1=\kappa_1\cos{\theta}+\kappa_2\sin{\theta}$ and similarly for $\overline\kappa_2$? Am I right?

Comment: I don’t think we have any relations between the principal curvatures, just the principal directions! Am I missing something? What he calls the curvature operator most of us call the shape operator (or derivative of the Gauss map).

Comment: @TedShifrin Thank you. You are right. I misunderstood the info. So then $\theta$ is the angle between the eigenvectors of the shape operators $\boldsymbol{\overline\kappa}$ and $\boldsymbol{\kappa}$?? Is that so?? But then I am not sure how the expression is obtained. Do you have any hints?

Comment: I haven’t thought about it. Have you used the fact that isometric gives you equal Gaussian curvatures?

Comment: @TedShifrin Yes. It reduces the expression a bit. But I am not sure how to bring in the supposed angle between principal directions. Thank you for being so patient. The same expression is also mentioned in this paper : https://cims.nyu.edu/gcl/papers/zorin2005cbe.pdf . But there is no elaboration here either.